# Horizontal and vertical scrollbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have `HorizontalScrollView` with wide `ListView` or `ScrollView` inside. I always see horizontal scrollbar but vertical scrollbar located out of the screen in right side of scrollable area. How can I make vertical scrollbar always visible too?

for example

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="exampleexampleexample\nexampleexampleexample\nexampleexampleexample\nexampleexampleexample\n"
            android:textSize="300sp" />
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Do not put a listview in a scrollview

Comment: @tyczj I added some sample code. I don't put ListView inside ScrollView (both vertically) I know what will happens in this case :)

Comment: It's probably defined by the [`fadeScrollbars`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fadeScrollbars) attribute.

Comment: @corsair992 unfortunatelly this attribute just make scrollbar always visible but I still must scroll to the right edge of the ListView to see scrollbar but I want to see scrollbar always in any position